# How to obtain Typescript type representing any of a group of API methods?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I think my non-compiling code will explain what I'm hoping to achieve:

```js
const fileWaiter = (method: keyof fs.promises) => async (filename: string) => {
  do {
    try {
      return await fs.promises[method](filename);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code !== 'ENOENT') {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  } while (true)
}
export const waitFileContents = fileWaiter(fs.promises.readFile);
export const waitFileStat = fileWaiter(fs.promises.stat);
```

I think TS transforms might be something that could achieve this, but I'm really trying to do this kind of light metaprogramming to make code general and less repetitive, I'm not looking for tools with which to grossly over-engineer anything. I was hoping that there is some easy way to do this, but it seems that the complexity of the node.js types here inherently make it impossible to map to something like what I'm trying to do, e.g. my intellisense is telling me that `typeof fs.promises.readFile` is

```
(path: string | Buffer | URL | fs.promises.FileHandle, options?: {    
    encoding?: null;                                                  
    flag?: fs.OpenMode;                                               
}): Promise<Buffer>;                                                  
(path: string | Buffer | URL | fs.promises.FileHandle, options: {     
    ...;                                                              
} | ... 9 more ... | "hex"): Promise<...>;                            
(path: string | ... 2 more ... | fs.promises.FileHandle, options?: "ascii" | ... 9 more ... | (fs.BaseEncodingOptions & {                    
    ...;                                                              
})): Promise<...>
```

And for `stat` this is:

```
(path: fs.PathLike) => Promise<fs.Stats>
```

I can accept that these were manually built, meticulously maintained types, and I should be able to set the type of `method` to the union of these two types, but it seems restricting and I wanted a quick way to indicate plainly that I want TS to use e.g. the union of all of those methods.

Comment: Having gone through your code - can you explain what `fileWaiter` is actually meant to do? Why is it calling fs methods in an infinite loop and rethrowing exceptions? How is that adding value?

Comment: @Dai It's just an asynchronous analogue to a busy loop that delivers you the file contents (or the signal that the file came into existence if you use the stat version) once the file comes into existence.

Comment: @StevenLu - With no delay in that loop at all, that's going to really hammer your disk and some of your CPU.  Yes, there's an `await`, but you're just firing that await as fast as it resolves.  This is not efficient code.  I'd hate to run this on a battery operated device too.

Comment: This is for a unit test and it's a race condition and I'm trying to avoid using sleeps... those dont work well if your system is under resource contention. it shouldn't loop more than one time.

Answer (score 1):

So, since it seems possible to accept this either as a limitation or as a quirk of fate, then I set out to write it the dumb way:

```
const fileWaiter = (method: (typeof fs.promises.readFile | typeof fs.promises.stat)) => async (filename: string) => {
  do {
    try {
      return await method(filename);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code !== 'ENOENT') {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  } while (true)
}
export const waitFileContents = fileWaiter(fs.promises.readFile);
export const waitFileStat = fileWaiter(fs.promises.stat);
```

Now this compiles and I'm still working on coming up with a way to generalize listing out the methods I want to be able to use with it in a cleaner way.

Comment: This way makes more sense to me. Still, I think you will want some kind of timeout too. Hitting your system like this over and over again can't be good.

Comment: So the problem with this is I can't figure out how to make typescript happy to let me feed the arguments through properly. might ask a separate question about that.

Comment: Do you know about generics?

Comment: Hmm I'll have to give that a try, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Wow so I think I forgot to think about using generics for this whole thing. Because it kind of solves all the problems.